# How to use a custom context processor?

Tags: python, django

I have written my index action:

```
def index(request):
    return render_to_response('app/index.html', {
        'title': None,
        'questions': build_questions(),
        'blocks': build_blocks()
    })
```

But I need to pass an app name for all actions, so I have decided to move it in the context processor:
**context_processor.py**:

```
from asknow.settings import APP_NAME


def global_processor(request):
    return {'app_name': APP_NAME}
```

And in **settings.py** I connected it to all context processors:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates/')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'asknow.context_processor.global_processor'
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

But it doesn't work, of course... What am I doing wrong?
**P.S.** I use Django 1.11.6.

**ADDED**
[image: Title screenshot]
It is a default header, not my site name.  In **base.html** I am trying to print my `app_name`.

```
<head>
    <title>
        {{app_name}} {% if title %}&nbsp;-&nbsp;{{title}}{% endif %} 
    </title>
</head>
```

My **index.html** extends **base.html**: `{%  extends 'common/base.html' %}`

Comment: What do you mean with "It does not work"? Can you provide the template you render?

Comment: `{{ app_name }}` in your template should work

Comment: @HenryM, I know but it doesn't work

Comment: @Шах: dit you restart the server. As far as I know, changing template files does not always triggers a server restart.

Comment: Do I need to do some actions yet but the addition of my context processor to all others?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, yap, I have restarted a gunicorn service

Comment: I would be very amzed if this solves it, but I always call my context processor files `context_processors.py` and everything else looks right to me

Comment: @HenryM, maybe do I need to run `manage.py` or some else? I am a noobie in python and Django

Answer (score 1):

It works with using of [`render`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40262346/3253896) only:

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'app/index.html', {
        'title': None,
        'questions': build_questions(),
        'blocks': build_blocks()
    })
```